# How to change syncfusion datagrid language ( localization)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid, localization, syncfusion

When grouping columns in `Syncfusion Datagrid  winforms`  its appears like : `"column name" : record - 10 items`. how can change [items] language or can i change it to another word ?

Comment: [Localization in DataGrid (SfDataGrid)](https://help.syncfusion.com/windowsforms/datagrid/localization)

Comment: i dont find "items" word in the resources file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word you mentioned is defined as the default group caption format in string type. It does not have a localization resource key, so we cannot change this word using localization. However, your requirement to change the word in GridCaptionFormat in SfDataGrid can be achieved by customizing the DrawCell event. Refer to the below code snippet,

```
//Event Subscription
sfDataGrid1.DrawCell += OnDrawCell;

// Event customization
private void OnDrawCell(object sender, DrawCellEventArgs e)
{
      //Here customize based on your requirement
      if (e.DataRow.RowType == RowType.CaptionCoveredRow)
      {
           // Check language and change the text accordingly
           if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name == "fr-FR")
               e.DisplayText = e.DisplayText.Replace("Items", "Unid");
      } 
}
```

**UG Link:** [Caption Summary](https://help.syncfusion.com/windowsforms/datagrid/conditionalstyling#caption-summary)

**KB Link:** [Group Caption Text](https://support.syncfusion.com/kb/article/8205/how-to-customize-the-group-caption-text-in-winforms-datagrid-sfdatagrid)

Comment: this work with any word right?

Comment: Yes. You can customize based on your scenario.